# Convert a map object to array of objects in Java script

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to JS.

I have a map object.

```
 Map {$Central: 265045, $East: 178576, $South: 103926, $West: 272264}
```

I would like to convert it into an array of objects

```
 [ {region:"Central", value: 265045}, {region:"East", value: 178576},
 {region:"South", value: 103926}, {region:"West", value: 272264} ]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `forEach` callback on `Map`

```
var res = [];
map.forEach(function(val, key) {
    res.push({ region: key, value: val });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `for ... in` to iterate over the keys of an object (map). Also, it looks like your object has properties that start with a dollar sign and your desired result has those stripped out.  You can use `substring` to do that.

```
var a = [];
for (var k in map) {
    a.push({region:k.substring(1), value:map[k]});
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
// Create the map
let locationsMap = new Map();
locationsMap.set('$Central', 265045);
locationsMap.set('$East', 178576);
locationsMap.set('$South', 103926);
locationsMap.set('$West', 272264);

// Convert the map to an array of objects
let locationsArray = Array.from(locationsMap, item => ({[item[0]]: item[1]}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use for..in loop to iterate the Map object and push the items in array.
Inside for..in loop create an object with properties region and value, push this object into an array.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>For in example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var map = {
  "$Central": 265045,
  "$East" : 178576,
  "$South" : 103926,
  "$West" : 272264
};
var arr = [];
for (var prop in map) {
var item = {region : prop.substring(1), value:map[prop]};
arr.push(item);
}
console.log('Map Object --> ',map);
console.log('Array of objects  --> ',arr);
  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```